# Returning dictionary of Promises for asynchronous EmberJS route

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm learning how to use Ember promises with async routes, and stumbling a bit here. If I write my route like so:

```
App.ActivitiesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return getClient().getActivities()
    }
});
```

Where `getActivities()` returns an `Ember.RSVP.Promise` type, I can use in my template:

```
{{#each activity in model}}
```

However, I would rather not have my entire base model subsist of a single attribute. When I try this:

```
App.ActivitiesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return {
            activities: getClient().getActivities()
        }
    }
});
```

And change my template to:

```
{{#each activity in model.activities}}
```

I receive an error message:

```
"Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed {_id: 82, _label: undefined, _state: undefined, _result: undefined, _subscribers: }"
```

And I'm not sure how to return a *named collection of Promises* that can be accessed individually in my template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model` needs to return a promise in order for the promise-based transition mechanisms to work property. You're not returning a promise; you're returning a hash of promises, which is an entirely different thing. You can return a hash-valued promise which fulfills when all its individuals keys fulfills with `Ember.RSVP.Promise.hash`:

```
model() {
  return Ember.RSVP.Promise.hash({
    activities: getClient().getActivities()
  });
}
```

This promise will resolve to a hash that looks like `{ activities: activities }`. Remember, all else being equal this is what will be set as the `model` property of your controller. Therefore, in the controller and in templates, you will now need to refer to `model.activities`.

If you want to wait for several asynchronous calls (such as multiple calls to `this.store`) to finish before transitions proceed, you can use the same hash approach in your model hook:

```
model() {
  return Ember.RSVP.Promise.hash({
    activities: getClient().getActivities(),
    toys: this.store.findQuery('toy', type })
  });
}
```

and then set the "main" one as the `model` on the controller in `setupController`:

```
setupController(controller, model) {
  controller.set('model', model.activities);
}
```

In some cases, a simpler approach would be to retrieve the main model in the `model` hook, and use `afterModel` to retrieve and wait for the secondary model.

Comment: Thanks - the `hash` function was exactly what I was looking for.